# Tagsinput not loading inside bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I can't able to load bootstrap tagsinput inside the bootstrap modal popup,
however its working fine on the normal page.

I am using this code inside a modal controller also i am using `$modal.open` to open modal:

```
$('#insidetags').tagsinput('add', 'some,tag,inside');
```

I have created [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcyj3q6q/982/) link for that, please check them out.

Comment: for starters, you need to stop combining angular and jQuery code, jq should only be used inside directives. this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Were you able to find a solution?